# Remove the underline from edittext in android

Tags: android

I am using a edittext with multiline property.when i type any word there is no underline but as i used space or enter key all the text cover by underline .how it can be remove . I dont want to see underline .so please give me any solution..

my xml file is......

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/etext"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="@null"/>
```

Comment: android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: There is no changes with this . any other thing.

Comment: you need to create custom drawble background

Comment: Can you please send me the requirement ,which you want

Comment: I am writing something on imageview through edittext as soon an i use space or enter key all the text covered by underline .but i want text without

Comment: underline. is it possible ? if then how. did u get whatever i want?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean underlines that come with auto-suggestions.
If you don't want them, try this

`android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`

in your EditText xml.

Comment: Can you attach screenshots, please, so we can better understand what kind of underlines are you talking about?

Comment: Try to load screenshots on some open file hostings and share the links here.

Comment: just use dropbox or any other file sharing service and put here the links.